# jQuery UI Date Picker - Range change by clicking another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is my current code. It is jquery ui date picker with setting a default start date and end date. Default start date and end date are working. What I want is when I click the #mybutton, I want my default start and end date change to new start and end date. So I set new variables within click function of #mybutton. But it is still getting default start and end date.

I guess my problem is because of javascript global and local variable scope. So I tried placing variables in all places (inside or oustside of functions). But still not getting new start date and end date.

Suggestion plz?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minDate = "default start date";
    var maxDate = "default end date";

    $("#myDate").datepicker({
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: maxDate,
    });

    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        var minDate = "new start date";
        var maxDate = "new end date";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to update the options of the datepicker:

```
  $("#myDate").datepicker("option", {
    minDate: newMinDate,
    maxDate: newMaxDate
  });
```

The demo below shows it in action. I've also added a function which checks if the current selected date is outside the new range of dates, if it is then it clears the value. The default action of jquerui datepicker is to move the selected date to the nearest date within the new range.

You can have a play by using the checkbox and reseting the demo to see the different behaviours.

Let me know if you needed something else.

```js
// Setup datepicker on page load
var minDate = new Date(2018, 11, 8);
var maxDate = new Date(2018, 11, 24);
$("#myDate").datepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  maxDate: maxDate,
});


// Add click event to button
$("#myButton").click(function() {

  // Create new dates
  var newMinDate = new Date(2018, 11, 10);
  var newMaxDate = new Date(2018, 11, 16);

  // Check if selected date is outside of range
  // Comment this out if you want the date just to be changed to within the new date range
  checkSelectedDate(newMinDate, newMaxDate);

  // Update options for datepicker
  $("#myDate").datepicker("option", {
    minDate: newMinDate,
    maxDate: newMaxDate
  });

});


function checkSelectedDate(newMinDate, newMaxDate) {

  // Exit if checkbox is not checked
  // Only needed for demo purposes
  if ($("#clearDate").prop("checked") == false) {
    return
  }

  // Get current date
  var selectedDate = new Date;
  selectedDate = $("#myDate").datepicker("getDate");

  // Check if it is outside the new range of dates
  if ((selectedDate < newMinDate) || (selectedDate > newMaxDate)) {

    // Clear date as outside of range
    $("#myDate").datepicker('setDate', "");

  }

}


// Reset date range to restart demo
$("#reset").click(function() {
 
  var minDate = new Date(2018, 11, 8);
  var maxDate = new Date(2018, 11, 24);

  $("#myDate").datepicker("option", {
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate
  });

});
```

```css
$("#myDate").datepicker( {
  minDate: minDate, maxDate: maxDate,
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div>

  <input id="myDate">

  <button id="myButton">Change Date Range</button>

</div>

<hr>

<div>

  <button id="reset">Reset Demo</button>

  <input type="checkbox" id="clearDate" checked>Clear date

</div>
```